# Android SDK and AVD Manager not listing SDK Platforms

Tags: android

I am just getting set up to do Android app dev using Eclipse 3.6 on Windows, and am following the instuctions at developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html.

When I open the repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, only 7 packages are found: 6 are "Google APIs" and 1 is the "Usb Driver package".

There are no "SDK Platforms Android" listed! Therefore, I can't install a platform.

When I look at the XML in a browser, it looks like there are platforms in it, but the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" is not displaying them.

Answer (score 2):

(Thanks, ranjanarr, but I already checked that.)

I found a solution to this problem: launch the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" from the "SDK Setup.exe" application file (this is Windows), instead of launching it inside Eclipse. When you do that, it works correctly.

Also, when I did this, I suddenly had access to the "Settings" window, which isn't there when I launch it from Eclipse. This allowed me to check the box for forcing it to use "http" instead of "https".

Then, after that, I closed the SDK Manager, restarted Eclipse, and launched the SDK Manager from Eclipse, and now all of the packages are listed correctly. (I still don't have access to the Settings page when I launch it this way, however.)

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse, preference>android>see if you have added the sdk location path. SDK location is the location where you have downloaded and extracted the folder to. 
After that, you will have to "force add" the APIs. Not sure if it is any close to your question.

Comment: best thing is to follow each and every step in adroid dev guide, word by word and it should work.