# Android SDK Manager does not load packages

Tags: android, eclipse

My android sdk manager doesn't do what it suppose to do.. it doesn't load any platform or anything. I have platforms(2.2 and 3.0) in my AVD manager. i want to download new platforms via the manager..

http://sphotos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/c46.0.403.403/p403x403/285633_483768121663593_628178710_n.jpg

Comment: You can use [imgur.com](http://www.imgur.com) for uploading images. What are you having trouble with? You can't download new platforms?

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to post pics.. yup, cant see any platforms to be downloaded in sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the SDK tools, I can see that package is available on your list. If that doesn't help then you might find these links helpful:

[Windows - Android SDK manager not listing any platforms or packages to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519383/windows-android-sdk-manager-not-listing-any-platforms-or-packages-to-install)

[Android SDK and AVD Manager not listing SDK Platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267060/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-not-listing-sdk-platforms)

[Android SDK manager does not show packages to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314359/android-sdk-manager-does-not-show-packages-to-be-installed)